# Get limited word of a string

Tags: php, html

So I am getting a sting from database which contains my `html` tags. Now I don't want the whole string I just wanted some part of it so I used `substr()` to short my string now it is showing my string with `html` tags. I don't want to show my `html` tags.

**This is how I am doing:**

```
<?php 
    $content = $news['content']; 
    echo substr($content, 0, 100)."...";
?>
```

**Result:**

```
<p class="boldp">  Overall Employer in World and No.1 in Pharmaceutical i...
```

**Desire Result:**

```
 Overall Employer in World and No.1 in Pharmaceutical i...
```

How can I remove these `html` tags from my string.

I don't know if anyone have asked this question or not. I tried finding solution to this but I didn't  find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [strip_tags](http://php.net/strip_tags):

```
echo strip_tags($news['content']);
```

Answer (score 2):

//Function Limiting words.....

```
function limit_words($string, $word_limit)
{
    $words = explode(' ', $string);
    if (count($words) > $word_limit):
        return implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, $word_limit)) . "...";
    else:
        return implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, $word_limit));
    endif;
}
```

//Function Limiting characters.....

```
function limit_characters($string, $length = 100, $append = "&hellip;")
{
    $string = trim($string);
    if (strlen($string) > $length) {
        $string = wordwrap($string, $length);
        $string = explode("\n", $string);
        $string = array_shift($string) . $append;
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Function to clean text content and do the following

/* 
 * Strip HTML Tags 
 * Clean up things like `&amp;` 
 * Strip out any url-encoded stuff 
 * Replace non-AlphaNumeric characters with space 
 * Replace Multiple spaces with single space 
 * Trim the string of leading/trailing space 
 */

```
function clean_text($text)
{
    return trim(preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/', ' ', urldecode(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($text))))));
}
```

Comment: `$news['content'] = '<p class="boldp">  Overall Employer in World and No.1 in Pharmaceutical i';
$content = clean_text($news['content']);
var_dump($content);` I have test this code and its giving me desire result and not showing "p" of "<p>" and also if you don't want (dot) in text `No.1` to be replaced with 'space' then edit clean_text function and add (dot) in `preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9. ]/'`