# Trim string to certain character in php

Tags: php, string, trim

I want to restrict my string to certain characters in php

```
$str = "I am asking question in stackoverflow, thank you for answering ";

$noOfChar = 11;

$trimStr = trimstr($str, $noOfChar);

echo $trimStr  . '....';

**output** 
I am asking question....
```

I am not sure which php fuction to use for this.

Comment: You mean, you want your string after your position 10? What is the desired result of this?

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358575/get-limited-word-of-a-string/27359512#27359512

Comment: @lolka_bolka I have edited the question and added expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use PHP sustr function...

```
substr($str, 0, 10);
```

http://php.net/substr

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for below given stuffs...

```
$str = "I am asking question in stackoverflow, thank you for answering ";
$substr = substr($str, 0,10);
echo $substr;
```

Comment: If you don't even know the question, how can you answer it? (expect guessing)

Comment: even if we give answer by guessing, it may help someone if it's right..   our motto should not be just limited to develop our own profile ... it should be help one another... :) @Rizier123